# IIS7.5 AppFabric - no Deploy option

Tags: wcf, deployment, appfabric

I am trying to deploy a WCF service to AppFabric however there is no Deploy option when I right click on the default web site in IIS manager.

Yes this is a new install.

Anybody got any ideas on how to activate this

Answer (score 1):

Actually I just found that I had to reinstall (did a complete install) MSDeploy and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Server AppFabric requires .NET/CLR 4.0 - my guess is that the default website has a CLR 2.0/.NET 3.5 application pool backing it up (which is the default.) Rather than use the default web  site, you'd be better of to create a new web site with its own application pool, set to use v4.0. This should enable the import/export application contenxt menus.